# Small Jquery animate function issue

Tags: jquery, function, hover, jquery-animate

I'm using this Jquery animate function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").hover(function() {
        $("#mask").animate({            
    width: 'toggle', left: '+=0'}, 250, 'easeout');
    });
});
```

When a user hovers over the trigger span area (`<span id="trigger">`), the mask (`<div id="mask">`) slides left. The mask then returns to position when a user moves his mouse away from the trigger region.

It works perfectly.

However, if a user's mouse is hovered over the trigger span area when the page loads, the mask slides in reverse, that is, while the user hovers over the trigger span, it slides into position. When s/he moves away from the trigger region, the mask slides left.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using 'toggle' and a single handler.  So the toggle occurs on mouse enter and mouse exit.  If you start in the trigger div, exiting makes it toggle the first time.

To fix this, use two handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").hover(function() {
        $("#mask").animate({
            width: '0px',
        }, 250, 'easeout');
    },function() {
        $("#mask").animate({
            width: '100px',
        }, 250, 'easeout');
    });
});
```

Of course, you have to have the width of your `#mask`.  If it is variable, you can still work around this.

Comment: This is exactly correct. I was just testing it on a fiddle before you beat me to it. Just an observation while testing, animating width with static values instead of `toggle` will not hide the element (if it has borders, they will still show when it reaches 0). At least the issue is pinpointed and the OP should be able to pick it up from here. Voted up

Comment: As the French say, you fellas are "les best." Many thanks for the assist.